# Opening multiple shells with tcsh script

Tags: kde-plasma, tcsh, konsole

Currently working with kde3.5

Here is what I would eventually like to do to help my workflow:

Have a script that:

- Opens multiple konsole shells
- Renames each shell

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -fv
set KPID =ps -ef | grep konsole | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'| tr "\n" " " 
dcop konsole-$KPID konsole newSession
```

The `dcop` command works just fine in command line (substituting variable for actual pid) but when I run it through the script, it gives 'object not accessible' error. No other errors present.

I've made sure permissions are ok (777) and even added sudo with it, but no luck.

As per second part again I have it working on command line:

```
dcop $KONSOLE_DCOP_SESSION renameSession "name"
```

This however only works for the active (working) shell and am not sure how to get it to do it for the others. I have not put this part in script yet as I am still working on the first part. Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Should `!/bin/tcsh -fv` be `#!/bin/tcsh -fv`?

Comment: Yes. It actually is in the script. First post here and when I did the #, it made the post bold so i removed it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a script, it doesn't need to be tcsh. see http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt

But if you want to pass $KPID into your script, use $1 in your script argument #1), and call it with

script $KPID